# How to fix this error regarding getSupportFragmentManager()?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

recently i started a new project in android studios and came across an error I can't really find or see the problem with, my application crashes when it hits the line getSupportFragmentManager(). I am using it alongside of TimePickerFragment

I tried googling different things and trying different ways to implement this

**ButtonListeners class**

```
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class ButtonListeners extends FragmentActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View buttons) {
        switch (buttons.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                **FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();** //<< error here
                timePicker.show(manager,"timepicker");

        }
    }

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
      //do something
    }
}
```

**TimePickerFragment class**

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
2019-06-18 16:29:24.449 25857-25857/com.example.calendar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.calendar, PID: 25857
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2114)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:683)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:637)
    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:144)
    at com.example.calendar.ButtonListeners.onClick(ButtonListeners.java:28)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Is your Activity you're starting actually `ButtonListeners`? Can you show us the code where you are setting `ButtonListeners` as the OnClickListener for a button?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getFragmentManager() in place of getSupportFragmentManager().
There is second option, using getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: when i try using getFragmentManger, its crossed out, is there a reason why?

Comment: `getFragmentManager()` is deprecated. You should not be using it at all, ever as it has many bugs that will never be fixed plus no support for any architecture components (such as Lifecycle, ViewModel, etc)

Comment: @ianhanniballake what should i be using then?

Comment: You should answer my comment on your question.